# Secret Dialog box

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I'm working on an android app , we need a custom dialog box to input some settings once in a while . This custom dialog box need to be hard to find so only some users can find it , like a `onLongClick` somewhere .
Any Ideas ?

Comment: You can archive this by set number of clicks , let say 15 clicks in particular time, Or you can set long click time etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just think out of the box, what android users are not familiar of something that is not user friendly, the LongClick action every android users do long clicks so do something like a swipe up or down on a button or image be creative :)